# Trim end of queue primary_connection_string and send to keyvault using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am able to store full primary_connection_string to keyvault for service bus queue in Azure using terraform. But not able to store the same value without ;EntityPath=*********

Original Connection String : `Endpoint=sb://****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey=;EntityPath=*****`

Required connection string to store in keyvault: `Endpoint=sb://****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey=`

I tried below code using replace but it did not worked. Its directly storing the string "azurerm_servicebus_queue_authorization_rule.que-referee-sr-lr.primary_connection_string". I need value as defined above:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "que-referee-sr-lr-connectionstring" {
  name = lower(format("%s-%s", azurerm_servicebus_queue_authorization_rule.que-referee-sr-lr.name, "primary-connection-string"))
  value = replace("azurerm_servicebus_queue_authorization_rule.que-referee-sr-lr.primary_connection_string", "/;EntityPath.*", "") 
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.PlatformKV.id
}
```

Comment: Try `replace(azurerm_servicebus_queue_authorization_rule.que-referee-sr-lr.primary_connection_string, "/;EntityPath.*", "")`.

Comment: @MarkoE it did not worked. Again got the same whole value without any trimming

Comment: @MarkoE it worked. added extra / in the statement. Instead of "/;EntityPath.*" i made it "/;EntityPath.*/".
Thanks for your input to remove the "" from my statement. Thank you very much. Cheers.